# jqtouch tabbed page container

Tags: jqtouch, tabbed

I am trying to implement a tabbed container (jquery organic tabs http://css-tricks.com/organic-tabs/) in jqtouch. I would like the tabs to only tab the content that is in the specified container. The problem is I cannot for the life of me override the default link behavior of jqtouch. When the user clicks a tab link it automatically switches to a blank page rather than displaying the tabbed content.

In short jqtouch sees the anchor and by default swaps to a new page, I would like in this case to display the content in the current page.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

jQTouch is thinked for mobile version of website. to leave less work to you some greats function are alredy implemented. Unfortunately some functions are not userful to you. In your case i think you just have to assign a jquery function for each tab to prevent page changing.
I hope the code i use will work for you too.

```
$('.contents').hide(); // hide all contents in page load
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tab1'.).click(function(){
$('.contents').hide(); // hide the current contents
$('#content1').show(); // show the current contents of your tab
}
});
```